# Dynamic reload of Java Keystore

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

It is possible to reload the Java Keystore without restarting the Apache Tomcat Service? I would like to change the certificates and allow my application to reload this new certificate from the keystore and use it, without having to restarting Tomcat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)

Answer (score 0):

I thought about starting an embedded server that will handle the incoming SSL handshakes and afterwards will redirect the traffic to Tomcat local port (without SSL). In case of changes in your key store just restart the embedded server (should be done quickly). Have you tried that?